# predicate error: entity is not key value coding-compliant for the key "@count"

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

when I was trying to find if a relationship of MyEntity is nil or has a count of of 0, I get this error. I tried both "someRelation == nil" and "someRelation.@count = 0" separately. The former worked fine, but the later keep raising this error. I'm pretty sure both the entity and relation names are correct, or the former shouldn't work either. Can anyone help me understanding why this is happening?

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<MyEntity>(entityName: "MyEntity")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "someRelation.@count = 0")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    let result:[MyEntity] = try context.fetch(fetchRequest2)
```

Edit: someRelationship is a to-one relationship. Its reverse is a to-many relationship. I’m using core data.

Comment: It's a "to many" relation? Meaning, how is defined `someRelation` in your `MyEntity.swift`?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: @Larme it is a to-one relationship. The reverse is a  to-many relationship. I’m using core data. Does that help?

Comment: So you can have only one `someRelation` in `MyEntity`? So it's not an `Array` (or `Set` in fact), so `@count` can't be used on it. It's either there or not (if optional, else how is it defined?)

Comment: @Larme thank you! That must be it. It is an optional relationship.

Comment: @Larme everything is by default on that relationship and entity too. So if I want to fetch the entities where the relationship is empty, do you know what’s the correct way to do it? Also if you want to post an answer I’ll accept it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the tip, I think Larme answered my question!

Comment: It's not empty. Imagine you have `struct MyStruct { var myVar: UIViewController? }`, how do you know that `myVar is empty"? You can check if it's `nil`. That's all, no?

Comment: @Larme okay, so I’ll just check if it’s nil. I’m actually not familiar with querying core data and I honestly thought all relationships are sets...

Comment: I would try `NSPredicate(format: "someRelation = nil")`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I get it now, haha thanks!

Comment: Don't you have a `MyEntity.swift` autogenerated file (by XCode or third party like SwiftGen) ? How is `someRelation` defined in that file?

Comment: @Larme I actually never had the need to do that. Core data can autogen those. Maybe it’s a good idea to generate the files and check it now.

Comment: You don't have a class MyEntity in your project? You access it only with its "String" name, and you access its value with `value(for:)`?

Comment: @Larme actually those are managed by core data and hidden, but you can generate them and manage them yourself if you want to.